# Xmtv player, monetization not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I tried to change a little from the main code xmtv offered web player. but does not go as I'd like.
In principle not open video ads. or if open not appear in the page as seen, not numbered in my account.

What did I do wrong?
here is the source
http://xmtvplayer.com/monetization

```
private void canalda2buton() {
    Button accionentrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCanalD2);
    accionentrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xmtvplayer.watch.live.streams","org.zeipel.videoplayer.XMTVPlayer"));
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (activities != null && activities.size() > 0) {


                Bundle bnd = new Bundle();
                bnd.putBoolean("NoExitPrompt", true); // Exit from player with one click of back button

                bnd.putString("adszone", "adqnq3hq-14zlpp44-vuutd"); // change adszone with your own id.
                bnd.putInt("adstime", 30);

                Intent i =  new Intent();
                i.setPackage("com.xmtvplayer.watch.live.streams");
                i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://80.86.107.169:8100/stream.flv"), "video/*");
                i.setClassName("com.xmtvplayer.watch.live.streams", "org.zeipel.videoplayer.XMTVPlayer");
                i.putExtras(bnd);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);



            }
            else {






                final Toast tag = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Te rog Instaleaza Playerul Necesar pentru a putea vizualiza canalul dorit!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                tag.show();

                new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000)
                {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {tag.show();}
                    public void onFinish() {tag.show();}

                }.start();


                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        .setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xmtvplayer.watch.live.streams"));
                startActivity(goToMarket);


            }








        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adzone defined from you are id from AdIquity, to start receiving ads, you must fill form defined in section “how to monetize” to receive from us Ad Id which is related to yours. That is required because we are trying to add more ad networks to XMTV Player. Currently I define id for you which is “50CDFE59-47DC-4DBD-B7EE-9BCE6E81C101“. Please change it in your code. Also change way how you pass Video Uri:

```
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(“http://80.86.107.169:8100/stream.flv”), “video/*”);
```

with

```
bnd.putString(“path”, uri);
bnd.putString(“name”, Title);
```